# Protecting your Laravel API from unauthorized application access

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I've been reading on tutorials on how to make Laravel APIs such as the one [Here](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-6-rest-api-with-passport-tutorialexample.html).

The authentication that is being used in the tutorial is based on the token that is generated when user logs in or out of the Api.

I was wondering if it is possible to protect the API from unauthorized access other than apps with an API access key?

Example:

```
'headers' => [
  'Accept' => 'application/json',
  'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$accessToken,
  'Api-access-key' => 'the-secret-to-accessing-this-api'
}
```

Result if api-access-key is *authenticated*: **let Laravel communicate with http request**

Result if api-access-key is *NOT authenticated*: **deny request**

Comment: Are you asking about having a 2nd authorisation mechanism? So either a valid `$accessToken` *OR* valid `Api-access-key` will allow API access?  Or it is meant to be a 2nd layer, or ... ? Hard to understand what you are trying to do, or why.

Comment: A valid api-access-key would allow the client to access the API (Read). the $accessToken is for user auth (Create Update and Delete). Or am i looking at this all wrong? Cheers, Deathking